# Can you do a double inheritance to one database table?

Tags: sql, database, inheritance

I am attempting to set up a section of a database for employee records. One set of inheritance I am trying to get done is pay based on salary or hourly rates and info associated with such with example below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8YP7.png)

I also want to do an inheritance based on the type of person it is due to the differing types and number of licenses that each employee may or may not have. So I want to do an inheritance of that as well with this example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eDnL.png)

I am unsure if it is possible to have to different types of inheritance for a single class or if I need to need to add an sub class from either one of the examples to combined all the info. Which one of these two break downs would be ideal.

Option 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hyh.png)

Option 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtUx8.png)

Comment: Interesting question, +1. You are modelling two **aspects** of the entity Employee. I would suggest you separate the Employee entity from its aspects, to produce: Employee, EmployeeTypeAspect, and EmployeePaymentAspect. Then, each aspect will have inheritance on its own. That way it would be a lot easier to model in your programming language.

Comment: I don't quite follow what your getting at. If I see understand you correctly it would be the bass employee class and then I could just do each aspect like a normal subclass of employee (with respect to their separate sub section)?

Comment: Not exactly: normal class Employee with a 1-1 relationship with the EmployeeTypeAspect, and also a 1-1 relationship with the EmployeePaymentAspect.

Comment: Do you have a link to something I could read to better understand?